# How can I get ejs to work with mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

I have a route that gets all of the clients and I'm trying to pass the client to ejs to render them. I'm getting the following error:

```
Express
500 SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
at Object.Function (unknown source)
at exports.compile (/Users/sm/Desktop/AttApp/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:234:12)
at Object.exports.render (/Users/sm/Desktop/AttApp/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:273:10)
at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/Users/sm/Desktop/AttApp/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:303:22)
at View.render (/Users/sm/Desktop/AttApp/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:75:8)
at Function.app.render (/Users/sm/Desktop/AttApp/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:503:10)
at ServerResponse.res.render [as partial] (/Users/sm/Desktop/AttApp/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:721:7)
at ServerResponse.module.exports.res.render (/Users/sm/Desktop/AttApp/node_modules/express-partials/index.js:55:9)
at ServerResponse.res.renderPjax (/Users/sm/Desktop/AttApp/node_modules/express-pjax/pjax.js:17:11)
at Promise. (/Users/sm/Desktop/AttApp/app.js:61:17)
```

Here is my route:

```
app.get( '/clients', function( req, res ) {
    return ClientModel.find( function( err, clients ) {
        if( !err ) {
            res.renderPjax('clients/clients.ejs', {
              title: 'Clients Page',
              clients: clients

            });

            console.log(clients);
        } else {
            return console.log( err );
        }
    });
});
```

And here is my view client.ejs:

```
<input type="text" class="table-search" id="search" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search Clients…">
<table class="table" id="tblData">
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Client Name</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
            <tbody id="tblDataBody">
            <% clients.forEach(fucntion(client){ %>

                <tr>
                    <td><a href="http://lar4.loc/clients/<%= client._id %>"><%= client.first_name %></a></td>
                    <td>Title</td>
                </tr>

            <%  }) %>

            </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I get the ejs template to loop through the client data and render it? I'm using mongoose to store and fetch the data. I'm also using express.js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is due to error in this line

```
<% clients.forEach(fucntion(client){ %>
```

Since you mis-spelled `function` it cannot account for `{`